# How can I get access to the data in the gpuMat?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

[opencv document about gpu::orb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufXSw.png)

I want to get the keypoints of the image with gpu::orb and the type of the keypoints is a gpuMat.Then I tried to get access to the data of the gpuMat as the documents.

I tried with the code below:(keypoints is a gpumat)

```
cout<<keypoints.ptr<float>(3)[4]<<endl;
```

but I got a "Segmentation fault(core dumped)".I knew that we can't modified the data in the gpuMat.Then how can I get the data in the gpuMat?

Answer (score 3):

According to [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html) `cv::cuda::GpuMat` is:

> Base **storage class for GPU memory** with reference counting. Its interface matches the Mat interface with the following limitations:
>
> - no arbitrary dimensions support (only 2D)
> - no functions that return references to their data (because **references on GPU are not valid for CPU**)
> - no expression templates technique support

`ptr` would return the pointer to device memory. You cannot read device memory directly from host. In order to use the data in host functions like `operator <<`, the data needs to be copied to host memory using `GpuMat::download(cv::Mat& m)`.